# How to run a process in background depending on a flag in ksh

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, ksh

In KSH, I want to run multiple commands run in parallel or sequentially in background depending on a flag.

So if the FLAG is true it will run like this:

```
command1 &
command2 &
command3 &

command4 &
command5 &
command6 &
wait
command7
```

But if the flag is false then I need to run command1, command2 and command3 sequentially. But it should not impact running of commands: command4, command5 and command6 as a parallel batch themselves. 
So if the flag is false:

```
(command1; command2; command3;) &
(command4; command5; command6;) &
wait
command7
```

I may be able to achieve it using if-elses, but is there a nicer more correct way of doing this?

I am using ksh88 on Solaris 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shell specific flag that would allow automatically grouping commands in background batches. Here is how it can be done with a simple `case/esac` construction:

```
case "$flag" in
(true)
    command1 & command2 & command3 &
    command4 & command5 & command6 &
    true
    ;;
(false)
    { command1; command2; command3; } &
    { command4; command5; command6; } &
    true
    ;;
(*)
    echo "Unexpected flag: [$flag]"
    false
    ;;
esac && {
    wait
    command7
}
```

Comment: Yeah, didn't find any other way. Used this. Thanks!